# Why the Item deleted from an array but isn't deleted from my table?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtable

I've put together a few methods that are suppose to delete a searched item from an array and the data from the array is also being put into a JTable through a method called `createLoginTable()`.

When my delete button actionListener Method is carried out the element or login is successfully deleted from the array: 'listOfLogins' but the element does not appear to be deleted from the JTable as it is still there.

Here are the methods starting with the actionListener:

```
if(e.getSource()==deleteLoginButton)
    {
        int loopNo = list.nextLogin; ///Variables used in the 'removeLogin' Method
        String foundLogin = list.listOfLogins[foundLocation].toString();
        Login[] loginList = list.listOfLogins;

        LoginList list = new LoginList(); //The 'list' is wiped
        list.removeLogin(loginList, foundLogin, loopNo);

        list.writeLoginsToFile(); //Writes logins to file (not integral to the array)
        String[][] loginTableLogins = new String[50][2]; //Wipes the JTable Array
        createLoginsTable(); //Creates the JTable

        searchLoginButton.setEnabled(true); 
        editLoginButton.setEnabled(false);
        deleteLoginButton.setEnabled(false);
        addLoginButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

This is the 'removeLogin' Method (This is in a seperate 'list' class):

```
public void removeLogin(Login[] array, String unwantedLogin, int loop)
{
    for(int i=0;i<loop;i++)
    {
        String currentLogin = array[i].toString();

        if(!currentLogin.equals(unwantedLogin))
        {
            Login login = new Login();
            addLogin(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

plus 'addLogin' Method (although i am assured this is not the source of my issue):

```
public void addLogin(Login tempLogin)
{
    listOfLogins[nextLogin] = tempLogin; 
    System.out.println(listOfLogins[nextLogin]);
    nextLogin++;
    System.out.println(nextLogin);
}
```

And the 'createLoginsTable' method:

```
public void createLoginsTable()
{   
    for(int i=0;list.nextLogin>i;i++)
    {   
        loginTableLogins[i] = list.listOfLogins[i].toArray();
        System.out.println(list.listOfLogins[i].toString());
    }

    JTable loginsTable = new JTable(loginTableLogins, loginTableTitles);
    JScrollPane loginsScrollPane = new JScrollPane(loginsTable);

    loginsScrollPane.setBounds(400, 200, 200, 250);
    testPanel.add(loginsScrollPane);
}
```

I have used 'System.out.println's so I am 99% certain that the element has been removed from the array (it is also apparent through my `writeLoginsToFile` Method) So I hope this information helps.

Comment: Just looking what is the point of  `Login login = new Login();` within the remove method

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning the table after you delete the item.

When you call the method to delete it and write out the table, that table is not returned after you remake the table.

Take this:

```
JScrollPane loginsScrollPane = new JScrollPane(loginsTable);
```

Bring it outside of your method. What I think might be happening is when you create your loginsScrollPane locally inside the method, it's not being added properly to your testPanel.

I think what might be happening is when you add it, and the method ends it's loosing that data that is contained.  Declare your scrollpane, and your jtable where you declare your frame.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a little bit hard to decipher, next time maybe put in also the enclosing class, or some details about that class. What does the following line do:

```
LoginList list = new LoginList(); //The 'list' is wiped
```

You say the list is wiped, I think what is does is: it declares a list local variable and assigns a new object to it (and it masks the other list variable which you used a few lines earlier). Now, in the createLoginsTable() method you don't have this local variable, you have the "list" which I guess is a public field in your class. Now what you can do, is or pass the local list variable to the above function as a parameter createLoginsTable(list) or try the wiping line without the declaration so only:

> `list = new LoginList(); //The 'list' is wiped`

Anyway, your code seams a little bit troubled it, maybe you should refactor it a little bit. Hope it helps.